# cURL Login Issues for Streeteasy (zillow owned site)

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a site where realtors can create online presentations for clients and using examples from a website called streeteasy.com, a zillow owned site.  I can successfully scrape everything I want with the exception of you have to be logged in in order to see the sold price for closed properties.  The login is very low in security as far as I can tell and it sets a cookie for 10 years when you login.  I used the chrome developers tools to get the post data and the post URL.

You can see the page comes up just fine but it still says 'Register to see what it closed for about 5 weeks ago' to see the final sale price.  When you are logged in, the message is different.  I still cannot get this code to work and I have no idea why.  I am testing on my WAMP so the cookie.txt file is not an issue with permissions.  I even tried to just create my own cookie file with my browser cookies and just access the page but still no luck.

```
$url = "http://streeteasy.com/sale/1253471";
$login_url = 'https://streeteasy.com/nyc/user/sign_in';
$data = 'utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=MYCz6A5PK%2B3I3N%2BgHekaNc4IuQEruBrCPBjSxm1B9dg%3D&do=login&return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fstreeteasy.com%2F&origin=&page_category=&page_type=&boundary=&label=&remember=true&return_to_save_search=&login=john%40telesh.com&password=dman4578';

login($login_url,$data);
echo grab_page ($url);

function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    return curl_exec ($login);
}                  

function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    return curl_exec ($ch);
}
```

Comment: Did you MEAN to post your actual login credentials?

Comment: Does the login work? have you checked the output? Also, both functions have curl_init(), try to have only one, and pass the curl as argument, or set as global. And, there is no need for the extra code after return in each function, it will never run.

Comment: I do not care about that login info, there is no reason to have that protected, there is nothing gained by exposing it, but thanks for looking out.

Comment: This appears to be working when i've tested online. See here: http://flipdesign.co.uk/dev/stack/41946562.php

Comment: Jordan, thanks A LOT.  I did upload it to test on one of my servers and it does work, only thing is I do all my dev locally.  Anyone has any ideas why its not working on WAMP??  I can deal with it not working locally but it is just so much faster to work locally and I have a lot more to do

Comment: @ JTelesh @Jordan no, this script should not work at all. logging in on this site requires a "authenticity_token" to do a correct login, the code provided ignore this. also the login() function is so bugged that it should result in a `500 Internal Server Error` when calling the php script, because it never ends the output buffer.

Comment: I figured out the issue with my localhost. Curl gets an error due to SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.  So thanks guys for all the help, I have it all resolved and going to work the code into the project!  I also bring in the current token and clear the memory as needed

Answer (score 0):

(i hope that is a dummy account...) 
first off, to do a successful login, you need a valid "authenticity_token" which you get on the login page, which is probably different for each session, but your code has a HARDCODED authenticity_token which probably expired long ago, and was only ever valid in your browser. second, your login() function is so bugged that it *SHOULD* result in a `500 internal server error` when calling the script from WAMP, because the output buffer it creates is never ended. third, for some weird reason, seems it REQUIRES the login request to contain a browser-like `accept` header, for example `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8` , but curl, by default, just says `Accept: */*` - which it doesn't accept.

start a cookie session, grab the sign in page, parse out the authenticity_token from the signin page (actually, just parse out all the "input" tags), and log in with the fresh one, and make sure to send `Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8` with the login request.

using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php , here is a working example:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once ('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ();
$hc->_setComfortableOptions ();
$hc->exec ( 'https://streeteasy.com/nyc/user/sign_in' );
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$inputs = array ();
foreach ( $domd->getElementsByTagName ( "input" ) as $input ) {
    $inputs [$input->getAttribute ( "name" )] = $input->getAttribute ( "value" );
}
assert ( array_key_exists ( 'authenticity_token', $inputs ) );
$inputs ['login'] = 'john@telesh.com';
$inputs ['password'] = 'dman4578';
var_dump ( $inputs );
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( $inputs ),
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://streeteasy.com/nyc/user/sign_in',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' 
        ) 
) );
$hc->exec ();
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
if (false === strpos ( $html, 'You have successfully logged in' )) {
    throw new RuntimeException ( 'login failed! (could not find `You have successfully logged in` in the response body!' );
}
hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getResponseBody () );
```

- it dumps the logged in html at the end, proving that it has logged in. it even verifies this by checking for the `You have successfully logged in` string in the response.

-edit: as for parsing out the "sold for" price, you can use DOMDocument for that.. the html is shitty, so its a bit cumbersome, but i found a way to get it:

```
$hc->exec('http://streeteasy.com/sale/1253471');
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML ( $html );
$sold_for=NULL;
foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("div") as $div){
    if(false!==strpos($div->getAttribute("class"),'status_sold')){
        $sold_for=trim($div->nextSibling->nextSibling->textContent);
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($sold_for);
```

output:

```
string(63) "Sold for $16,550,062

          as of about 5 weeks ago"
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. I took your advice on all accounts and cleaned up my version using and its working great.

Answer (score 0):

If the token expires in such a long time, why not just hardcode the cookie session into your cURL requests, simply add the value for the cookie header to be:

```
$headers = [
    'Cookie: _actor=eyJpZCI6IitEZG9VenJLc00wVENZSXFYZWlrVlE9PSJ9--4d8449347e46c32eaae1a8189b83881b7abc6e24; _se_t=f9f7ae31-80cd-4698-bdc8-fbdff739009b; _gcl_au=1.1.73614610.1670886677; pxcts=48f6f381-7a72-11ed-bc8c-4d6a52455343; _pxvid=48f6e270-7a72-11ed-bc8c-4d6a52455343; _ga=GA1.2.1781461336.1670886678; __gads=ID=f12dde3526d46fa2:T=1670886679:S=ALNI_MY5HCF64ez59fkAePUrvcVo2YMjbg; zg_anonymous_id=%2222fd5f18-5b53-4213-8734-1983e805f19e%22; google_one_tap=0; ezab_gold_price_widget=no_widget; ezab_ursa_srp_expanded_map=reduced_map; last_search_tab=rentals; se%3Asearch%3Arentals%3Astate=false%7C%7C%7C%7C; se_login_trigger=8; ezab_orca_1999_show_agent_matches=show_agent_matches_immediately; onboarding_flow=false; se%3Asearch%3Ashared%3Astate=300||||false; anon_searcher_stage=initial; tracked_search=; __gpi=UID=000008d033ec5e0d:T=1670886679:RT=1671549920:S=ALNI_Mbh6kKe3MrPpvhniGrkDAtpQwm-Zg; se%3Abig_banner%3Asearch=%7B%229991594%22%3A1%7D; zjs_anonymous_id=%22f9f7ae31-80cd-4698-bdc8-fbdff739009b%22; _uetvid=485c00c07a7211ed8f4eeb1ea6ad9f20; ezab=%7B%22gold_price_widget%22%3A%22no_widget%22%2C%22orca_1999_show_agent_matches%22%3A%22show_agent_matches_immediately%22%2C%22ursa_srp_expanded_map%22%3A%22reduced_map%22%7D; _gid=GA1.2.608953748.1672024129; _pxff_cc=U2FtZVNpdGU9TGF4Ow==; ki_r=; g_state=; zjs_user_id=%222058917%22; remember_user_token=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6Ilcxc3lNRFU0T1RFM1hTd2lNbDl6U2paTWIzQlJNMEpZYzNNMlVsbDJjMU1pTENJeE5qY3lNREkwTWpJeExqWTBNRFk0TWpJaVhRPT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDMyLTEyLTI2VDAzOjEwOjIxWiIsInB1ciI6bnVsbH19--fac8f407a824eba1fb7aeac12d574c6bff565a20; user_auth_token=Q6_wPheB4hx2QseGxyy3; se_lsa=2022-12-25+22%3A10%3A41+-0500; _ses=MVUweDEySUpkZEo1c3pQek96OFpQTmgxWUoyTmIyeElaSWxhR0hCS2I2Z1VESnp4b3NnM2VJQm1Kelo2SzcxeHBIQkxBUmJwWE9zc20valdITU5XM2lRUTJhTjlSa3UzR3p0Yk5yTVJnR1pPQ0RuZ1hsZ1F0SzVCb1dEbkoxYWRCN0hYUzAxZlNZckZ1TVNxZ2diQTNzcXVVL2tIb0lNdk9nb09NNWw1V1p0NDFKNEFGcWp3SkQ2S1N4eElObjJqVWVxRm9IOEVyQXVUMEpORURadGxnUT09LS05S3JuL1Y2TWlNOEdaZFJPYWdlZ3RnPT0%3D--c9565ba32e0b2adae10d9076a0b7442b5edb5d81; ki_t=1670886678145%3B1672024129813%3B1672024241463%3B5%3B102; _px3=d3827445b59b0a26866c26cebaa57f08257be464948e0a69625cdc878a36c4af:bIEndpROKJiy9bn1Wb/Ez8jOc1wjprWLUJjlVz8c37ayGumhnRQ1s9VBQ6XmxIo/gzER64vFdxi2f60X6WLoPA==:1000:Re35eAC4PIw8oV16m1QenX871u0lx4QnQfNVNegIoEFZRiehpPIiiTARGdPIwr6O3A/Aey5zb9hn3BxkW0sD4fU+v/V1zNU/uIlbp9PByj+r4dE8usVlgb3G2grMJw5I+x/yH7N2T6qwRgDiyXcYLTRSCtiwnFQoDvvctIGTuOUOXZmpNUC40YzcPijIrv1UAzXyt0oahTIG815/me9QDA=='
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

This will set the header to send the auth cookie string the server checks against; As long as you pass the cookie, and the session is non-expired - you will be able to send all http requests successfully.

I wrote a few scrapers for Streeteasy, know that Distil Networks is the vendor whom they signed up for to protect their server from DDoS/Scrape/Dir Fuzzing - you will likely get banned after a few requests so make sure to use MiT proxy to hit that captcha page to whitelist your server.

Btw if on localhost you're experiencing the same SSL related errors I used to, add the following to your cURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPHOST, FALSE);
```

That out to do the trick; you'll be able to make calls with or without self-signed certs;